# How to fix distorted ie7 like button?

Tags: html, css, facebook, internet-explorer-7, facebook-like

The issue can be observed here:

[image]

It doesn't work on emulated ie7 (ie9 -> developer tools).

I tried with many css settings, but probably not with all of them, as I believe there is some solution for this bug.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its in quirks mode. Apply a proper doctype.

And if you using developer tools,

Change document mode to ie7 standards

Comment: What is proper doctype? Current is set to: <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">

Comment: Are you sure ? Because when I am testing. It shows a distored like button when its in quirks mode or ie9 standard with ie7 mode. But works fine with ie7 mode and ie7 standard

Comment: Yeah, I could provide screenshot that they are enabled:/ IE9 version is: 9.0.8112.16421

Comment: Yes, I can produce the same on localhost. `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">` fixes problem

Answer (score 6):

Jashwant's answer is essentially correct - what you're seeing is IE using the IE7 browser mode with IE9 document standard, in a real IE7 browser the Facebook Like button appears OK. The problem is with the IE developer tools.

When you first open the developer tools, they will display IE9 browser and document mode. If you change the Browser Mode to IE7, the Document Mode appears to automatically change to IE7 standards. However, if you then change the Document Mode to IE9, then back to IE7, you'll find that the Facebook Like buttons now display correctly.